Python code restarts with different version
The problem is whenever I'm trying to restart my code with admin rights, it starts with python 3.7.  Basically I just want to access admin rights not switching any versions. But according to my arguments and prints that I made, it should be python 3.12, which I currently use. I've tried using pyuac and some others options but it still has same result.
The code:
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
import win32con
shell.ShellExecuteEx(
    lpVerb='runas',
    lpFile='"' + sys.executable + '"',
    nShow=win32con.SW_NORMAL,
    lpParameters=' '.join(args)
)

The command that i used:
C:\Users\Username\PycharmProjects\My-project>python3.12 main.py "-startAsAdmin"
Python before restarting:
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
Python after restarting:
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe

Presumably your system-wide PATH is different than the admin user's. We can't see either, so you will need to [edit] your question to provide these details. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

The code doesn't generate output, where is the output coming from?

I have found a solution for my case. In my case i had to "Manage app execution aliases" then disable python and python3 variables that was taken by "Application installer"(?). After that I made sure that all evniromental variables were set and restarted the console.
(English is not my first language, some thing could be called in other way)

How about omitting using Python from your PATH and instead setting up a virtual environment and using it to execute your code.
This way you would force the interpreter to use a Python version defined by you instead of one of a set of versions stored in the path.
